# android CountDownTimer onStart

Tags: android, countdowntimer

i want to save the time when countDownTimer begin working, is there any method like onStart()?

```
timeToDirectAnswer = new CountDownTimer(25000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer starts ticking the moment `start()` is called on it. You can get the current time wherever `start()` is called.

Comment: i want to save the time when the timer begin working, if i save it on `onTick()`i will lose the first time

Comment: You can subtract the `countDownInterval` value from the current time, (or) see the edited answer.